# "A makes B good, and so does C"

Tags: grammaticality

This sentence is the short form of "A makes B good, and C makes B good too."

Then, what is the short form of "A makes B good, and A makes C good too?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly:

> A makes B good, as well as C.

Though this may be ambiguous (though it will probably be obvious from context).

Maybe this would be better:

> A makes B good, and makes C good as well.

Perhaps just say

> A makes B and C good.

Comment: But what if the sentence is a little more complicated like: "A makes B different from D, as well as C." That might be ambiguous.

Comment: @trVoldemort: either "A makes B and C different from D" or "A makes B different from D, as well as from C" - depending on which meaning you want.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that the "from" in the last "from C" makes a great different. The preposition marks what it means.

Answer (score 0):

> Either A or C makes B good

or

> B is good due to either A or C

or

> Both A and C make B good

However, the last form, implies that A and C are required simultaneously to make C good.

EDIT, post comment.

> A makes B good, as does C

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But here what I want is a clause as something additional. it's something like "A makes B good, (yes I admit that, but the same thing should happend to C too ...)"

Answer (score 0):

A makes both B and C good.

A makes either B or C good.

The latter could be used if A does not do so concurrently.